# Facebook Login through PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

While I am running the html code using below code, the login is happening successfully.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
  function loginpage_onload() { 
    document.forms[0].submit(); 
  }

</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="loginpage_onload();"> 
<form action="https://www.facebook.com/login.php" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="lsd" value="cdfvrtg" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="mymail.com"/>
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="inputpassword" value="mypass" tabindex="1"/>
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

but, when I am copying the same thing in a .php page and running the php, its not happening.
Prompt: "For your security, never enter your Facebook password on sites not located on Facebook.com"

Why it's working in .html and not in .php?

Comment: I don't know why it's working in html and not in php but it shouln't be working in html too. Why? Because you can save user's input with javascript before sending the data to facebook login and thus it's huge security problem. So facebook will not allow you to login user this way. Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.1 for facebook login solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do, in its current form, poses a security risk to end users of both Facebook and your website, and is therefore prohibited.

It's much more likely that you have a legitimate reason to let your users securely login to Facebook from your website. In this case, check out the [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1) documentation for their [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.1) for a push in the right direction.

To elaborate on why it's prohibited, Facebook won't accept a form submit from any other domain to prevent phishing attacks and other nasties.